# JSON built from expando object has set incorrect key and value for multilingual data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET core WEB API application I am creating a dynamic JSON for the API response and that is build using the Expando object.
I get data in multiple languages and after adding that in Expando object as Key/Value pair, When the dynamic object returns from the API the key and values get swapped. here is an example

```
public dynamic PrepareDynamicResult()
{
      var result = new List<ExpandoObject>();
      ExpandoObject country = new ExpandoObject();
      var countryData = new {
       Name= "<country-name-in-arabic>",
       Value= 70
      }; // This data I receive from DB

      country.TryAdd(countryData.Name, countryData.Value);
      result.Add(country);
      return result;
}
```

[image]

As we can see in the image this is what I get as a response in the API, where 70 should be my value and country name is my key name.

Anybody has any idea. Many thanks!

Comment: The code is not valid.  The variable country is not used.  The Anonymous object countryData is not declared correctly, and it does not contain a "TryAdd" method, and you can't add the   Anonymous object to result as it is not an ExpandoObject. So please post correct code so that we can help you better.

Comment: My bad, its typo, I corrected the code thanks, for countryData yes it a anonymous object for this example only but in my application I get data from DB

Comment: It is still not valid code!

Comment: you have "year" on your screenshot, but where is it in source codes? Do you mean it's a miracle? Also, I checked and this code on my side works correctly using System.Text.Json serializer.

Comment: the year is in my final result and I am very sorry I can't put my entire code, the code I added is just a sample, and the way I am doing the things,